# TSQL xml unicode inline assignment fails

Tags: xml, t-sql, unicode, internationalization

I have the following xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<products>
        <product>
              <ProductDescription><![CDATA[SOMETHIN''WHATEVER]]></ProductDescription>
        </product>


        <product>
              <ProductDescription><![CDATA[TYPICAL_TEXT ΜΑΣΚΑΡΑ]]></ProductDescription>
            </product>
</products>
```

which I want to make into columns. By searching around, I arrived at the following solution:

```
declare @input XML='copy-paste-my-xml'


SELECT 
Item.value('(ProductDescription)[1]', 'nvarchar(max)') as ProductDescription
from
@input.nodes('//product') AS T(Item)
```

Running the query produces this error:

> Msg 9420, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 XML parsing: line 9, character 57,
>   illegal xml character

The place indicated by the error is where the first Unicode character starts: `ΜΑΣΚΑΡΑ`. I deduce this because removing the unicode part makes the query run succesfully. But I've read that xml supports unicode. I also tried using N' but I got:

> Msg 9402, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 XML parsing: line 1, character
>   38, unable to switch the encoding

What should I do to get the unicode value?

Comment: XML does support Unicode. It is possible however that your xml parsing needs to be configured to match the same unicode serialisation, which should be UTF-8.

Comment: Your XML is in an ASCII string: `'xml here'`. Have you tried putting in a Unicode string: `N'xml here'`?

Comment: Your tag and comment @Dragonthoughts helped me solve this. I had to add N' AND change encoding to uts-16

Comment: @GeorgeMenoutis You are welcome, I do my best to help. May I suggest you actually complete answer, so we can help people in the future who have a similar problem?

Comment: I thought I'd wait for you to make one so I could accept...if not, tell me and I will make one myself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is two-folded:

1. You are using an xml declaration, stating, that the XML is encoded in `utf-8`. Within SQL-Server this is obsolet. There is no `utf-8` support on this level. So the XML is a liar.
2. You are using a literal like `'Some XML here'`, which is implicitly of type `CHAR / VARCHAR`. This *single-byte-encoded* string is *extended ASCII* with very limited support for foreign characters (uses a character map through collation). You should use the literal with a leading `N` to make it `NCHAR/NVARCHAR` with a wide range of *unicode support* (to be exact: `UCS-2`).

In my following example I use your XML without the declaration. It is best to omit this, as it is senseless within SQL-Server. But alternatively you can change `utf-8` to `utf-16` or `ucs-2`:

```
declare @input XML=
N'<products>
        <product>
              <ProductDescription><![CDATA[SOMETHIN''WHATEVER]]></ProductDescription>
        </product>


        <product>
              <ProductDescription><![CDATA[TYPICAL_TEXT ΜΑΣΚΑΡΑ]]></ProductDescription>
            </product>
</products>';


SELECT 
Item.value('(ProductDescription)[1]', 'nvarchar(max)') as ProductDescription
from
@input.nodes('//product') AS T(Item)
```